# Setting up very similar re-branded copies of our site and the influence on SEO

Tags: seo, duplicate-content

I'm in the process of setting up a "white-label system" for a website I've developed.  The website is a database of rental properties.   These replicated sites will be pretty much the same as the "main" original site but with visual differences for the different brands that are paying the website for the privilege of this service.

Some may look near identical with different colours and logo, others may be quite different with a lot of rewritten html.   The white label copies of the main site will run either at a subdomain of the main domain or on a totally custom domain of the whitelabel owners choice.

There's no trickery involved here, doing this is not a cynical ploy to try and get greater SEO rankings, these whitelabels will be authentic sites.  It's just they will be very similar.

The question is, are these often websites going to muddy the SEO results of the main website? -  which in terms of SEO is much more important to us.    And if so what should be done to alleviate this ?

Sure I could block all indexing of the white label sites by using robots.txt but is that really needed  ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what Google doesn't want. The white labeled sites will need to have canonical URLs back to the main site or be blocked altogether. Otherwise the main site, and all of the duplicate sites, will suffer.

Comment: *Are these often websites going to muddy the SEO results of the main website?* Hell yeah they will!

Comment: That's what I'd assumed @closetnoc but any productive ideas to avoid apart from blocking and what John said?